# How add attributes to catalog page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I try to add attributes to catalog page of the product.
In the file `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl`
I added this line

```
<p><?php echo $data['attribute_groups']; ?></p>
```

But I have an error `Notice: Undefined index: attribute_groups in`

Then I added this line to the 'catalog/controller/product/category.php'

```
 $data['attribute_groups'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

And now I have another error `Undefined index: product_id in`

---

first screenshot

---

[image: first image]

---

second

---

[image: second]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't even make sense
first there is no `$this->request->get['product_id']` in `category.php`

Second `$data['attribute_groups']` is a array and your are trying to echo it.

pass your attribute group in product array after

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

add

```
'attribute_groups' => $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($result['product_id']),
```

Now you can print value in

```
<?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
        <?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>
        <?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: THANK U MAN!!!!!!!!!!!!!
but some error was... I modified to 
`<?php if ($product['attribute_groups']) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { ?>
                  <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
                    <?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>
                    <?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>`